# How to use SetOnClickListener on a programmatic ScrollView Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, scrollview, onclicklistener

I created a `scrollView` programmaticaly that contains 20 views each with an image and a text.

I have two questions :

1 - is the id assignment correct and is my `setOnClickListener` correct?

2 - By which method `onClick` can I know which view of the `scrollView` the user has clicked?

See my code below

```
private var integerList: MutableList<Int>? = mutableListOf()
private var cellNo: MutableList<String>? = mutableListOf()
private var sv_mvmtChoosed = ""

private fun showSpinner() {
    /* SCROllL VIEW */
    var linearLayout: LinearLayout? = null
    linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linear1)
    val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this)

    var randIndex = 0
    for (posIndex in 0..19) {
        val rand = Random()
        randIndex = rand.nextInt(20)

        while (integerList!!.contains(randIndex)) {
            randIndex = rand.nextInt(20)
        }
        integerList!!.add(randIndex)

        // Create the view...
        val view: View = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.scroll_bckgrnd, linearLayout, false)

        // give it an id
        view.id = generateViewId()
        view.setOnClickListener(this)
        cellNo!!.add(view.id.toString())
        println(cellNo)

        //... then populate it with image and text
        val iv = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.iv)
        iv.setImageResource(sv_photoImage[randIndex])
        val tv = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv)
        tv.text = sv_photoName[randIndex]
        linearLayout?.addView(view)

    }

    // which view the user did select?
    fun onClick(view: View?) {
        when (view!!.id) {
            ??? -> doSomething
            }

        }
    }
```

Any idea to get me back on track will be welcome.

Comment: You can change view.id  or Add TAG to view. you can put postition as TAG. By Tag, you can get the item position when clicked. Or you can get postition of view within Linear layout.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably better to make a new `OnClickListener` for every view.

```
view.setOnClickListener(this)
```

needs to be this

```
view.setOnClickListener {
    // do something
}
```

or

```
view.setOnClickListener(createOnClickListner())

fun createOnClickListner():View.OnClickListener{
    return object :View.OnClickListener{
        override fun onClick(view : View) {
            //do something with the view that was clicked
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot avalerio.
I finally found a solution as follow :
I replaced :

```
// give it an id
    view.id = generateViewId()
    view.setOnClickListener(this)
    cellNo!!.add(view.id.toString())
    println(cellNo)
```

with :

```
// give it an id
    view.id = posIndex
    view.setOnClickListener(this)
```

then I did this :

```
// the onClickListener for my 20 images/text
        override fun onClick(view: View?) {
            when (view!!.id) {
            // Now de position clicked on the ScrollView
            in 0..19 -> didHeSucceeded(view!!.id)
            }
        }
```

And use the result:

```
private fun didHeSucceeded(scrllPos: Int) {
   // TODO: close de scrollView, how ? :-)
    
   spinnerChoice = nameOfTechScrollVw[scrllPos]
   succes = (!allreadyChoosedArray.contains(spinnerChoice)) && (currentArray.contains(spinnerChoice
            ))
   if (succes) {
      ...
      ...
}
```

It works perfectly